# What is the opposite of "conda upload"?

Tags: anaconda, conda

I built (`conda build...`) and uploaded (`conda upload`) a package to a private channel. It was a mistake and I would like to remove this package. What is the opposite of `upload`-ing? Surprisingly, I cannot find anything on this when I search online. From the docs, `conda remove` removes specific packages from an environment.

Comment: I believe `conda upload` uses the `anaconda-client` package to do its work. If you type `anaconda help` you may get somewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the package either through the web UI or the command line. To remove the package through the command line, use the following command:

```
$ anaconda remove jsmith/testpak
```

Source: https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda-repository/user-guide/tasks/pkgs/delete-pkg/